# How can i validate email confirmation token?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, html.actionlink, email-confirmation, request-uri

In my asp.net mvc application, when a user registers, I send a email to their account with a link for validation before they can use the app. See code snippet below.

```
        var emailActionLink = Url.Action("ValidateAccount", "Register",
            new { Token = registeredUserViewModel.Id, Username = registeredUserViewModel.Username },
            Request.Url.Scheme);
```

The snippet above is what they will click on which will then call an action with the route values,

**Validate Account Action**

```
    public ActionResult ValidateAccount(string token, string username)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                var user = _userServiceClient.IsUserNameAvailable(username);
                if (!user.HasValue) throw new NullReferenceException("This account does not exist");



                var userContract = user.Value;
                userContract.EmailVerified = true;
                if (_userServiceClient.UpdateUser(userContract) == null) throw new Exception("Something has gone wrong");
                return View("ValidationCompleted");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.RegisteredUser = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The problem is, this method is not verifiying the token, what will happen if someone changes the value of `token` in the uri, this will still pass and very the account. What will be the right approach in improving this.

In this case, token is the user's Id which is a Guid, but it is encoded and there is no way of comparing the user's Id in my database with this encoded token. I think this is encoded in the action link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using your Id, you would probably be better off having a Token field in the table (nullable, so that it can be cleared out after validation). Generate a URL-safe token (I use hex strings, which don't use any special characters), and then look for that token in the database in the validation action.

Here's an example of a token generator:

```
public class TokenGenerator
{
    public static string GenerateToken(int size = 32)
    {
        var crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] rbytes = new byte[size / 2];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(rbytes);

        return ToHexString(rbytes, true);
    }

    private static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes, bool useLowerCase = false)
    {
        var hex = string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString(useLowerCase ? "x2" : "X2")));

        return hex;
    }
}
```

Then, add the appropriate method to your service class:

```
public YourUserType GetUserForToken(string token, string userName)
{
    return YourDbContext.Users
        .SingleOrDfault(user => user.Token.Equals(token, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
            && user.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Obviously, this makes some assumptions on your table structure and data access code.

Comment: I realised, the URL sent to the email actually contains the user ID. I still think your approach is better, I have an EmailVerificationToken field in the DB already, and this is similar to the way i hash the passwords so i think i'm happy with your solution. I will refactor to use something like that